# What are some Maven project naming conventions for web application module?

Tags: naming-conventions, standards, maven

When creating a project with the webapp archetype in Maven, they subtly advise not putting any Java source in the webapp project by not including the "src/main/java" folder.

What do you name your Maven projects?

**project-webapp** for the project that contains the JSP, CSS, Images, etc.
**project** for the project that contains domain specific entities
**?** for the project that contains the web application files like Servlets, Listeners, etc.

My first inclination would be to use "webapp" for the project containing the web application files (Servlets/Listeners), however the archetype uses "webapp" to convey the JSP/CSS/Images project and would cause confusion to other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When creating a project with the webapp archetype in Maven, they subtly advise not putting any Java source in the webapp project by not including the "src/main/java" folder.

That's not really true. When you create a project with the maven-archetype-quickstart, you don't get a `src/main/resources` directory. Would that mean you should not put resources in this project? No.

> What do you name your Maven projects?

There is no general rules, nor conventions. Use something that makes sense for your organization and your team. But as I said above, your initial assumption is not true and putting Java code inside a maven war module is a common practice (except for code you want to share between modules).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this below link directly answers your question, but it makes sense to refer it

Refer their JIRA task here [Document the naming convention for archetypes](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2484)

As per this, the naming convention can be as below

The Artifact id of the archetype should be of the format -archetype-

Ex: +  maven-archetype-quickstart : Which indicates the archetype is from maven and the project is a quick start

Same way you scala-archetype-simple : Which indicates it is from scala and is a simple scala project

Best of luck